# Comparison of string

Tags: c, recursion

I've been sitting on a code for almost ten days right now.
I am writing a funtion that get two pointers for 2 different strings, and the function need to return 1 if there is the same number of words, or 0 if there isnt.

I am not allowed to use any lib, global or static int etc, no loops, only recursion, not allowed to change the signature of the function.
what I wrote is the delta between the two sentences. First my code calculates the sum of words in the first sentence, when it gets to the '\0' of the first sentence, it starts to work on the second sentence, and substract each time there is a word.
right now the output of my funtion is the delta, I want somehow to tell the function that if the delta ("the return") is 0 return 1, else return 1.

"

```
int same_num_words(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    printf("%s\n", s1);
    printf("%s\n", s2);
    if(s1[0]=='\0' && s2[0] == '\0')
    {
           return 0;
    }
    if (s1[0] == '\0' )  // AFTER first sentence is complete, substract the second sentence count.
    {
        if(s2[0]!= ' ' && s2[1]== ' ')
        {
            return  same_num_words(s1, s2+1) -1 ;
        }
        if(s2[0]!= ' ' && s2[1]== '\0')
        {
          return   same_num_words(s1, s2+1)-1;
        }
        return same_num_words(s1, s2+1);
    }
    if(s1[0]!='\0') // first sentence
    {
        if((s1[0]!= ' ' && s1[1]== ' ') || (s1[0]!= ' ' && s1[1]== '\0') ) // first sentence
        {
            return    same_num_words(s1+1, s2)+1;
        }
    }
        return  same_num_words(s1+1, s2);
}
"
```

any help?

Comment: I think you'd find it easier to have a recursive function count_words() that you call for both sentences and then compare the results.

Comment: *"if the delta ("the return") is 0 return 1, else return 1."* Is that a typo? Did you mean to say, *" if the delta ("the return") is 0 return 0, else return 1."*

Comment: If the instruction is that `same_num_words()` *itself* mus be recursive and must not call another recursive helper function (I can't read that from the question). I can't think of any other way than either passing  sth. like a recursion level to decide that you must return 0/1 instead of the delta of words or having an additional `int *` variable for the delta and always return 0/1. In both cases you have an additional parameter that makes no sense at all for an external caller of that function but I think that's because the instruction itself makes no sense ...

Comment: "return 1 if there is the same number of words, or 0 if there isnt." and `int same_num_words(char *s1, char *s2) { if(s1[0]=='\0' && s2[0] == '\0')   {        return 0;` returns 0 for `same_num_words("", "")`.  I'd expect 1.

Answer (score 3):

Each character is either a letter or delimiter (`'\0'` or whitespace: space, `\n` `\t`, etc)

1 - Any leading whitespace is irrelevant, so skip over those.
2 - If code is at the end of either string, we are done.
3 - Since each string now begins with a letter, see it the *next* character is also a letter.

```
int same_num_words(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  // printf("'%s' ", s1);
  // printf("'%s'\n", s2);
  if (s1[0] == ' ') return same_num_words(s1 + 1, s2);
  if (s2[0] == ' ') return same_num_words(s1, s2 + 1);

  if (s1[0] == '\0' && s2[0] == '\0') return 1;  // same
  if (s1[0] == '\0') return 0;  // differ
  if (s2[0] == '\0') return 0;

  // Both s1,s2 begin with a letter (non-delimiter)

  // If the next character is also a letter, skip over the current one.
  // as code is looking for the end-of-word.
  if (!(s1[1] == '\0' || s1[1] == ' ')) return same_num_words(s1+1, s2);
  if (!(s2[1] == '\0' || s2[1] == ' ')) return same_num_words(s1, s2+1);

  return same_num_words(s1+1, s2+1);
}
```

Expand `s1[0] == ' '` to `s1[0] == ' ' || s1[0] == '\t' || ...` as needed.

A key change from OP code was skipping leading spaces first as that consumes the string's  leading and trailing spaces.

---

For fun, a cleaner looking implementation with typically fewer recursions.

```
int same_num_words(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  int sp1 = *s1 == ' ';
  int sp2 = *s2 == ' ';
  if (sp1 | sp2) return same_num_words(s1 + sp1, s2 + sp2);

  int nc1 = *s1 == '\0';
  int nc2 = *s2 == '\0';
  if (nc1 | nc2) return nc1 & nc2;

  // Both s1,s2 begin with a letter (non-delimiter)
  // How about the next character?
  int nxt_let1 = !(s1[1] == '\0' || s1[1] == ' ');
  int nxt_let2 = !(s2[1] == '\0' || s2[1] == ' ');
  if (nxt_let1 | nxt_let2) return same_num_words(s1 + nxt_let1, s2 + nxt_let2);

  return same_num_words(s1 + 1, s2 + 1);
}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use a const in the question, only go ahead with the char pointer. I think it changed the whole thing, cuz Im not allowed to change the signature of the funtion.

Comment: @Tom, 1) Then just delete `const `.  2) Better to append this new requirement to the post : "not allowed to change the signature of the function".

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are no invisible chars, only ones that can see, so it's anything other then ' ' or '\0'.

Comment: there are some situations that it fails, if the number of words is equals, then it return 0, I cant seem to understand why.

Comment: The 2nd `(s1[0] == ' ')` should be `(s2[0] == ' ')`, shouldn't it?

Comment: yea I also think that, I changed it and checked the code, but it's not working

Comment: @Tom, fixed.  Missing `return` with `return same_num_words(s1+1, s2);`

Comment: @chux, could u check the example: 1: Today is Thursday
2:It has been early, it return 1 when it should return 0. I think it is because when it gets to the last 'y' it doesn't "add"...

Comment: `printf("%d\n", same_num_words("Today is Thursday", "It has been early"));` returns 0 for me.  Check to use latest code.

Answer (score 1):

This solution obeys the letter of the rules (although I did add some `const`). It overloads the meaning of `same_num_words` to return the number of words in the string if either of the arguments is `NULL`. The second argument is `NULL` if the previous character read (if any) was space, and the first argument `NULL` if we've just read a word character.

```
int same_num_words(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  if (!s1 || !s2) {
        const char *s = s1 ? s1 : s2;
        if (*s == '\0') return !s1;
        if (*s == ' ') return !s1 + same_num_words(s + 1, 0);
        return same_num_words(0, s + 1);
  }
  return same_num_words(s1, 0) == same_num_words(s2, 0);
}
```

Here's some unit tests to check the implementation.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct {
        const char *word1;
        const char *word2;
        int want;
    } cases[] = {
        {"This is a test", "one two three four", 1},
        {"", "", 1},
        {"one", "", 0},
        {"   one   two   three   ", "one two three", 1},
        {"one   two   three   ", "one two three", 1},
        {"one   two   three   ", "one two three four", 0},
        {"   ", "", 1},
    };
    int failed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cases) / sizeof(cases[0]); i++) {
        int got = same_num_words(cases[i].word1, cases[i].word2);
        if (got != cases[i].want) {
            printf("same_num_words('%s', '%s') = %d, want %d\n", cases[i].word1, cases[i].word2, got, cases[i].want);
            failed = 1;
        }
        got = same_num_words(cases[i].word2, cases[i].word1);
        if (got != cases[i].want) {
            printf("same_num_words('%s', '%s') = %d, want %d\n", cases[i].word2, cases[i].word1, got, cases[i].want);
            failed = 1;
        }
    }
    assert(!failed);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int check_words(char *str1, char*str2) {
    if (!str1 && !str2) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (!str1 || !str2) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (*str1=='\0' && *str2=='\0') {
        return 1;
    }
    if((*str1==' ' || *str1=='\t') && (!(*str2==' ' || *str2=='\t' || *str2=='\0')))
        return check_words(str2+1, str1);
    if((*str2==' ' || *str2=='\t') && (!(*str1==' ' || *str1=='\t' || *str1=='\0')))
        return check_words(str1+1, str2);
    if (*str1=='\0' && (*str2==' ' || *str2=='\t')) {
        return check_words(str1, str2+1);
    }
    if (*str2=='\0' && (*str1==' ' || *str1=='\t')) {
        return check_words(str2, str1+1);
    }
    if (*str1!='\0' && *str2!='\0') {
        return check_words(str1+1, str2+1);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry missed that criteria.

Comment: Hold on.. i guess there are still issues.. :(